# Laravel Vue add user details to comment array

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on laravel comment system with vue js, and facing a problem when doing axios request. I need to receive an array as a response with all the comments for the post, but I would like to add user data to this array to get username and rest of users details to display.

```html
public function show($id)
   {
      $comments = Post::find($id)->comments;
      return $comments;
   }
```

Current:

> [{"id":35,"user_id":1,"post_id":4,"parent_id":0,"commenttext":"test","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

What I would need is:

> [{"id":35,"user_id":1,"post_id":4,"parent_id":0,"commenttext":"test","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,
>   "user":[**User Data Here**]}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **nested** eager loading.

```
$comments = Post::with('comments.user')->where('id', $id)->first()->comments;
```

That should retrieve all comments with its `user` relationship.

```
foreach($comments as $comment)
{
    echo $comment->user->id;
}
```

Or I believe you can also do this. (**Lazy Eager** loading)

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->load('comments.user');
$comments = $post->comments;
```